# What are actually viable on-premise platform as a service implementations?

Tags: java, cloud, paas

Not sure if this is the right place to ask such question, maybe tell me where to move the question on another StackExchange site.

I'm evaluating cloud platforms and I have some business requirements to evaluate them against, so I'm trying to build small POCs for the products I found, but I'm not sure of which products I've included and excluded.

The PaaS I need is:

- On premise: I have a private infrastructure based on VMWare
- Java support: I have an IT dept that develops in Java language with Spring support
- Can connect to local legacy services (DB2 via JDBC, IBM Queues and so on)
- Complete: at least I need auto-scaling, monitoring, load balancing wth a comprehensive interface
- Integrated (integrable) with IDE: eclipse or other Java IDEs
- Integrated (integrable) with CI: automatable (scriptable) deployment to run with a CI like Jenkins or other

It seems to me there's much confusion among product offers. E.g. It's not always simple to verify if a platform is adoptable on a private data center.

Now I already have built two POCs and my attention is on these two products: vFabric and Stackato, but maybe I'm missing something important, so which are in you opinion the PaaS products that support the above technical requirements?

**UPDATE**

I also added to my list of viable solutions the following products/projects: Cloudify and Cloudsoft AMP.
I'm positively impressed by Cloudify and started to deploy it in a production environment for a limited set of applications.

Comment: Found something related on ServerFault: http://bit.ly/PQYA6D

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to cloud foundary. Since it is an Open-PaaS, it can be very useful for you and the things they don't have, you can create and contribute to them. So it will be win-win situation for both.